# Keep getting "the condition has length > 1" error on my if/else statement and ifelse()

Tags: r, if-statement, nested

Tried both if/else and ifelse() to remedy this error but keep running into a length error. Here is my current code:

```
for(i in CDF) {
  Combined$value <- if(Combined$region %in% CDF$label1[i]) {
   (mapData$total_goals)
  } else {
    (Combined$team)
  }
}
```

This is the error I receive:

```
Error in if (Combined$region %in% CDF$label1[i]) { : 
  the condition has length > 1
```

This is what I originally tried but still received an error:

```
for(i in CDF) {
  Combined$value <- ifelse(Combined$region %in% CDF$label1[i], 
     (mapData$total_goals), Combined$team) 
}
```

Comment: The first error is from the erroneous expectation that `if` can handle a logical vector of length greater than 1. And the ifelse error make it look like the number of values in `mapData$total_goals` is different than the number of rows in `Combined`.. To give a good answer we would need to see `str` done on both dataframes.

Comment: You could add a`message` to yourself, so you can see exactly what you fed to the `if` statement. For example, between `for(i in CDF)` and the `if` call, add `message(combined$region %in% CDF$label1[i])`. Then check the console to see what triggered the error.